# keypress not working when pressing key from url

Tags: jquery

I am using below code to encode url (code not written as of now for that) when pressed enter from url

```
$('.input').keypress(function(e) {
                // ESCAPE key pressed
                if(e.which == 13) {
                    alert("in enter");
                }
            });
```

but it is not printing this alert when I press enter from url.
I want to validate on input=% (inserted from url),so require it from url only.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "...from url."? Also, do you really have the class `"input"` on the elements you're trying to work with? Because that's what the selector `.input` looks for. Also note that your comment says you're looking for the "ESCAPE" key (keycode 27), not enter (keycode 13).

Answer (score 2):

The selector `.input` looks for elements (of any type) with the **class** `"input"`. It doesn't look for elements with the tag `input`.

If you're trying to select `input` elements:

```
$("input").keypress(...);
// ^----- no . here
```

Comment: $("input").keypress(function(e) {
       // ESCAPE key pressed
       if(e.which == 13) {
        alert("in enter");


       }
   });tried this,still not working.

Comment: T.J Crowder is right , it works : http://jsfiddle.net/AKxXr/

Comment: if i=I try it for textbox or any other input type it is working,it is not working when I am pressing enter key from URL.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder -from url means if I am pressing enter after giving inputs in url.class is "input" for the elements.sorry I forgot to change the comment,it should be enter only.
Thanks

Comment: @user2640846: The phrase *"...after giving inputs in url..."* is meaningless. If you update your question with markup and a [complete, self-contained example](http://sscce.org), maybe we can help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: have to do like this only,if any user types % in url ,then it is throwing IllegalStateExcepion,have to handle that .For that I have to encode my url which I have to do on pressing enter by user.eg
http://stackoverflow.com/appName.html?appName=%
this appName is a text field on my screen but if user enters it from url,then it is throwing exception.
Thanks